# Djangos data cannot be imported into the database, is my code wrong?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I am new to Django, and I'd like to ask some questions

I used the model layer to create the model with fields in it,it can create user_id,movie_id field in the database.

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    movie_id = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    rating = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=4)
    rating_timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    type = models.CharField(max_length=8, default='explicit')
  
    def __str__(self):
        return "user_id: {}, movie_id: {}, rating: {}, type: {}".format(self.user_id, self.movie_id, self.rating, self.type)

class Cluster(models.Model):
    cluster_id = models.IntegerField()
    user_id = models.IntegerField()
  
    def __str__(self):
        return "{} in {}".format(self.user_id, self.cluster_id)
```

Execute this statement using Python xxx.py,I want to populate the database but it doesn't work

```
import os    
import urllib.request
import django
import datetime
import decimal
from tqdm import tqdm
    
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')
    
django.setup()
    
from analytics.models import Rating
    
def create_rating(user_id, content_id, rating, timestamp):
    rating = Rating(
              user_id=user_id, movie_id=content_id, 
              rating=decimal.Decimal(rating),
              rating_timestamp=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
               float(timestamp)
               )
              )
    rating.save()
    return rating

def download_ratings():
    URL = 'https://gitee.com/zhangyoushang/wokkk/blob/master/latest/ratings.dat'
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
    data = response.read()
    print('download finished')
    return data.decode('utf-8')

def delete_db():
    print('truncate db')
    Rating.objects.all().delete()
    print('finished truncate db')


def populate():
    delete_db()
    ratings = download_ratings()
    for rating in tqdm(ratings.split(sep="\n")):
        r = rating.split(sep="::")
        if len(r) == 4:
           create_rating(r[0], r[1], r[2], r[3])

if __name__ == '__main__':
   print("Starting MovieGeeks Population script..." )
   populate()
```

But I found that my database was empty and there was no data in it.

No error is reported, execute as follows:

[image]

Comment: hi, have you migrated the database?
try ``` python manage.py migrate ```

Comment: yes,I  have used python manage.py migrate

Comment: I find the reason is the network problem